# simple array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, char

Ok so I'm a Java programmer, and I have an assignment for class (in C) which asks me to do the following:

" Create a single dimension array containing ONE index,
which will have ONE string with your full name "

So I know Strings in C are just char arrays, but I don't understand how I am supposed to fit an entire string in one char index?

```
char name[1] ; //initializing to 1 index
name[0] =  “David Baez”  ; // setting that one index "0" to my name
```

How would you go about this properly?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Give us a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried the example above, but I know it is wrong. I am wondering if my professor worded the question incorrectly, because it doesn't seem like what he is asking is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll just give hints. Put aside arrays for a moment. If you wanted to create a string with your name, you could write `char* name = "David Baez";`.

Now assume you need to take five of those strings (which again, are each of type `char*`), and put them all in one array. How would that look? Once you've got that, it's trivial to make the array contain just one element.

Answer (score 2):

> but I don't understand how I am supposed to fit an entire string in one char index?

You are not supposed to. `char name[1]` is an array with size `1` which can only store a single character. If you want to store `"David Baez"`  then you need to specify an array of size `11`. If you are not sure of the size then just do this:

```
char name[] = "David Baez";
```

or

```
char *name = "David Baez";
```

But mind you modifying the latter (`*name`) will lead to UB.

Comment: Or... better stick with std::string

Comment: @GreenScape C-only question. Noone learns C++ nowdays in schools :(

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question; his assignment requires an array with a single index, but you're telling him to use an array of size 11.

Comment: Why would he say: " Create a single dimension array containing ONE index" ?

Answer (score 1):

> Create a single dimension array containing ONE index, which will have ONE string with your full name.

That would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char *myName[1] = {"Pax Diablo"};
    printf ("%s\n", myName[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why this is so:

- It is in array with one dimension, the first (no `[x][y]` stuff).
- It only has one index, the first one of `0`.
- It has one string with the full name, by virtue of the fact it's an array of character *pointers.*.

Comment: Please don't give homework answers away; that doesn't help students to learn concepts they need help on.

Comment: I'm not the least bit concerned with giving answers to assignments. I'm only concerned with explaining _why_ an answer is right. If I'd just provided the answer, I'd probably vote it down myself :-) But giving an answer along with the explanation _is_ educating the student.

Comment: The explanation helps, but IMO it's still better to give hints and let people figure out as much as possible for themselves. That's the best form of learning.

Comment: @paxdiablo the array `myName` should be `const` qualified.

Comment: @musical_coder In case the question is bad and doesn't make any sense, the student deserves to know it. That alone is a good reason to answer questions like these.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have an array of length 1 containing a string, use pointers:

    `char *name[1];
    name[0] = "David";
    printf("%s\n", name[0]);`

The above defines an array of length 1, its element is a pointer(char *).

Answer (score 1):

> So I know Strings in C are just char arrays...

Not quite. Strings are character arrays containing a terminating null byte.

> ...but I don't understand how I am supposed to fit an entire string in
>   one char index?

You cannot. How can you fit multiple characters in one character space? Think about it. What you can possibly do is

```
// an array of characters
char name[] = "David Baez"; 

// an array of a single pointer to a const char
const char *namep[] = "David Baez";
```

Answer (score 0):

The task doesn't make any sense. A string in C is indeed just a character array.

However, it says array, so you can use an array type. Then there's a weird, artificial alternative, which is unlikely to make you a better C programmer...

```
typedef struct
{
  char name[50];
}struct_t;

struct_t s[1];
strcpy(s.name[0], "David Baez");
```